# How to slow down a fade effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this very old post here [Fade text when page scrolls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671993/fade-text-when-page-scrolls) and found a particular bit of code by @Ruben-Infante and I wanted to know how I slow the fade down. As when I scroll with the mouse wheel it vanishes almost instantly.

http://jsfiddle.net/q7u4d/2/

I am thinking it must be to do with the JS, though when I played around with the numbers I could not get the effect I wanted. Any help would be great.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var top = ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) ? $(window).scrollTop() : 1;
    $('.fade').stop(true, true).fadeTo(0, 1 / top);
    $('.fade').css('top', top * 1.3);             
});
```

Comment: just change the values  $('.fade').stop(true, true).fadeTo(0, 1.2 / top);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fadeTo's first parameter is the speed of the fade in ms.

I see your speed is set to 0. Try this for a 1 second fade (line 3):

```
$('.fade').stop(true, true).fadeTo(1000, 1 / top);
```

Docs:     [api.jquery.com/fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q7u4d/303/

Comment: I reccomend using the actual source over w3schools http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/. in this instance it may be accurate but w3 is notoriously inaccurate and out of date

Comment: Thank you all this helps alot.

Comment: Random question, another member mentioned easing (though they seemed to have removed their post). How do I combine the CSS easing (shown here http://easings.net/ ) with the JS code without using there JS addon.

Comment: @psilocybin deleted my last question as I figured it out. My other question is can I link the fading to the position of the scrolling? So it is at 50% at one point down the page 25% at another.