# How to link a fade on scroll to the position of the scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I asked a question last week on how to slow down a scroll effect [How to slow down a fade effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063747/how-to-slow-down-a-fade-effect)

The help I got was brilliant and answered what I asked, but it is still is not doing what I want it to do.

Rather then slow the fade effect, I instead want to link it to the position on the page the viewer is currently seeing. So if I scroll down the page by 20px the opacity is at 10% for example (and will be like that again if I scroll back into the same position).

I have tried searching for a similar effect but couldn't find one. As such I am wondering is this even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by link to position on page? Do you want to define gradient stop points in your page?

Comment: @norcal_johnny had the right idea. I am now just qondering if there is a non jQuery way to do it.

Comment: @Schro Sure there is give me a few minutes and I will update my answer.

Comment: @Schro oh nevermind it looks like someone just posted a js version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear from the question what exactly you want to achieve!

I have updated the fiddle so that instead of a fade effect, the scroll will set an opacity according to the div's height when you scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.fade').css('opacity', 1 -  ($(window).scrollTop() / $(".hero-unit").height()));
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7u4d/304/)

**Edit 1**

If you want to avoid jQuery dependency, here is the simplified Javascript for the same.

```
var fadables = document.getElementsByClassName('fade');
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('hero-unit')[0];
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var winTop = window.pageYOffset || documentElement.scrollTop || body.scrollTop || 0;
  var containerTop = container.offsetHeight;
  var opacity = 1 - winTop / containerTop;
  for (var i = 0; i < fadables.length; i++) {
    fadables[i].style.opacity = opacity;
  }
});
```

See [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7u4d/305/)

Comment: That is also exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Schro I have added plain JS code to do the same. Please check.

Comment: Is there a way to make the effect happen sooner? If so which parts would I need to adjust?

Comment: `1 - (winTop / containerTop * x)` you can play around with the value of x, maybe 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

Here the Javascript code the will set an opacity (0.5) to element with scroll top is greater than 20px. And reseting the opacity if scroll top is lesser than 20px.

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
var org_opacity = document.getElementById('element_id').style.opacity;
if(org_opacity == null || org_opacity == "")
{
    org_opacity = 1;
}

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
       document.getElementById('element_id').style.opacity = (1 - document.body.scrollTop / 200); /* set the opacity that you want */
    } else {
       document.getElementById('element_id').style.opacity = org_opacity; /* reset the opacity to its original value */
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't get yours to work, do you have a jfiddle version?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? You can adjust it based on distance, opacity. I believe it behaves different.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 200);
  });
```

```html
<div class="custom"  >
 <div class="top"><img style="position: relative" src="http://stanfordflipside.com/images/279puppies.jpg"></div>
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I meant. Is there a way to do this without jQuery?